# Is there a more effective way to transform coordinates?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a picture on canvas that I want to do a trapezoidal distortion on. The code itself is ready, but it is slow, very slow. 400x400 images in ~10-20 seconds on an i7 desktop machine. However, I want to run this on a mobile device with maximum camera resolution, so I'm looking for a more efficient way.
Currently, my code works like this:

1. request the coordinates of the distortion rectangle from the user. I need to get the quadrature coordinates from the user
2. I divide the sides a and c into 400 parts.
3. I iterate over the previous division, so I take the point on the 1/400th part of the side "a" and the point on the 1/400th part of side "c". Then the section between the points on the 2/400 part. And so on.
4. I divide the section I have just produced by 400 and iterate over that as well.
5. I take the line number produced in point 2 as "X" and the points in point 4 as "Y". The coordinates of the given points are Q and W.
6. I take the pixel on the original canvas at coordinates "Q" and "W" and draw it on the target canvas at the location identified by coordinates "X" and "Y".

[image]

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There is a non-affine transform proposal that was drafted [here](https://github.com/fserb/canvas2D/blob/master/spec/perspective-transforms.md) and it even got implemented in Chrome for a while but unfortunately all graphic engines don't support such transforms natively and it's been "parked" for now.

Answer (score 0):

As your essentially operating on the pixel level things have to be pretty slow. The fastest way would be to utilize WebGL and outsource the calculations to a fragment shader. That might be a bit of an overkill in this case though. If all you want to do is perspectively transform an image, there's a ready-to-use tiny library - though not as acurate as on the pixel level - which might suite your needs called [perspective.js](https://github.com/wanadev/perspective.js/)

All you have to do is feed it an image and your desired four corner points.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let p = new Perspective(ctx, image);

  p.draw([
    [65,43],
    [266, 16],
    [304,251],
    [26,151]
  ]);
}
image.src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1079/200/300";
```

```css
canvas {
  border: gray solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wanadev/perspective.js/master/dist/perspective.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This tiny lib is great, and fast enough. But I need the inverse transformation. So I have the original image, from which I would like to highlight a part. Not to put the whole image in perspective. I see that the two operations are very similar, but I don't know how to apply this solution. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Impulsively I'd say that's doable yes but I'm unsure how that highlighting would look like. Maybe you can add an image to your original question?

Comment: Well, I'm not a good drawer, I tried to draw this the first time, but I guess I failed. I'll try to write it down :) So I want to stretch the quadrilateral with the sides "abcd" on the original drawing to the same size as the picture that contains it. So if I have the "abcd" quadrilateral on a 100x100 image, then after transformation the endpoints of the "d" side are (0;0) and (0;100).  Likewise, the endpoints of side "b" would be (100;0) and (100;100), regardless of what coordinates the quadrilateral in the drawing had. This is the transformation I would need.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't have a picture in my mind. =) What about using your working very slow algorithm to process an input image and post the input and output of it?